# How to apply a linear transformation to a parametrically-plotted disk with a texture?

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, parametric-functions, textures

Short version: I would like to apply a linear transformation to a parametrically-plotted surface with a texture and get an output with the correct texture.

First, I used `ParametricPlot[` to plot the unit disk with a texture (in this case, the Wolfram Language logo):

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
               PlotStyle -> {Texture[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqcj8.png"]],
                             Opacity[1]},TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)]
```

The output looks like this:

[image: output1]

Next, I defined a simple linear transformation. In this case, just a counterclockwise rotation:

```
s0 = Pi/3
rot[s_] = {{Cos[s], -Sin[s]}, {Sin[s], Cos[s]}};
```

In theory, I should be able to apply this linear transformation to my unit disk and see the same image rotated by s = Pi/3 (with the texture correctly applied):

```
ParametricPlot[rot[s0].{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[Import["https://tinyurl.com/y8t8r5fj"]], Opacity[1]}, TextureCoordinateFunction -> (rot[s0].{#1, #2} &), TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

But instead I get the following:

[image: output2]

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

It seems like I am applying the linear transformation correctly in the `TextureCoordinateFunction`, but somehow the `TextureCoordinateScaling -> True` option is not being applied.

Note: I know that there are ways of achieving the desired behavior using graphics primitives and `Rotate[`, but this is for a beginner-level linear algebra exploration so I want to use the machinery of linear algebra.

**Update:**
While the example above only has a rotation, I'm hoping to appropriately transform the texture for any non-singular linear transformation. For example, I'm hoping to have the texture applied appropriately even if I replace `rot[Pi/3]` with `rot[Pi/3].{{2, 0}, {0, 1}}` (a scaling matrix and a rotation) or any matrix such as `A = RandomReal[{-3,3},{2,2}]` where `det[A]` is nonzero.

The top answer notes that the texture coordinate system scales coordinates to run from 0 to 1 when using `TextureCoordinateScaling`, so the clever fix for applying a rotation correctly is to translate from the texture coordinates system's center of (1/2,1/2) to the origin, perform the rotation, then translate back to (1/2,1/2). However, a scaling matrix will still cause problems even with the translation:

[image: output3]

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to use `TextureCoordinateFunction->(toTransform[Inverse[A]][{#1,#2}]&)` so that the texture and the disk are transformed in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

The texture coordinate system runs from $(0, 1)$ for each coordinate when using [`TextureCoordinateScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextureCoordinateScaling). To rotate the image, you need to rotate around the coordinate $(1/2, 1/2)$, not the origin. So, I think the following does what you want:

```
texture = Texture @ Import["https://tinyurl.com/y8t8r5fj"];
ParametricPlot[
    {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle->{texture, Opacity[1]},
    TextureCoordinateFunction->(RotationTransform[Pi/3, {1/2, 1/2}][{#1,#2}]&)
]
```

[image]

**Update**

The OP wants to use a matrix instead of a [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction). Here is a way to convert a matrix into a [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction) suitable for transforming the texture:

```
toTransform[m_] := Composition[
    TranslationTransform[{1/2,1/2}],
    AffineTransform[m],
    TranslationTransform[-{1/2,1/2}]
]
```

Here I use `toTransform` along with your `rot` function, where I've adjusted the direction of rotation so that the disk and the texture are rotated in the same direction.

```
ParametricPlot[
    rot[Pi/3].{r Cos[t],r Sin[t]}, {t,0,2 Pi}, {r,0,1},
    PlotStyle->{texture,Opacity[1]},
    TextureCoordinateFunction->(toTransform[Inverse@rot[Pi/3]][{#1,#2}]&),
    BoundaryStyle->None
]
```

[image]

**Update 2**

Here is the transformation matrix from the update to the question:

```
A = rot[Pi/3].{{2,0},{0,1}};
```

And here is the [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot) using the transformation matrix `A` (note that the [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse) is used in the `toTransform` function so that the disk and the texture are both transformed in the same way):

```
ParametricPlot[
    A . {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t,0,2 Pi}, {r,0,1},
    PlotStyle->{texture,Opacity[1]},
    TextureCoordinateFunction->(toTransform[Inverse@A][{#1,#2}]&),
    BoundaryStyle->None
]
```

[image]

Comment: And if you want to do it directly with the linear algebraic formulation, look at RotationTransform[Pi/3, {1/2, 1/2}] alone, which gives the correct matrix and translation-offset to use.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great start. And it is certainly possible to do it directly with linear algebra with some homogeneous coordinates (https://i.imgur.com/DHUE1Yb.png). 

Unfortunately, I'm trying to get this working for any non-singular linear transformation, A. For example, I should be able to define `A = RandomReal[{-3,3},{2,2}]` as long as `Det[A]` does not equal 0.

Any ideas for generalizing this technique with a fairly random looking linear transformation that can be decomposed into A = U.D.V* where U, V are unitary matrices, V* is the transpose of V and D is a scaling matrix?

Comment: @WorfSonOfMogh Yes, I agree. I don't know why that happens.